# How to get value from html control store as variable using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a variable in JavaScript like following :

```
var testVariable="<input type='radio' name='gender' value='male' checked> Male<br><input type='radio' name='gender' value='female'>Female<br>"
```

Now I want to get the value of radio button which has attribute **`checked`**.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can parse the string as HTML

```js
var testVariable = "<input type='radio' name='gender' value='male' checked> Male<br><input type='radio' name='gender' value='female'>Female<br>";

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc    = parser.parseFromString(testVariable, "text/html");
var val    = doc.querySelector('input[type="radio"][checked]').value;

console.log(val)
```

Comment: I wanted exactly same you mentioned :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can stuff the string into some element's `innerHTML`, then perform DOM selection on it normally:

```
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = testVariable;

const checkedInput = div.querySelector('input[type="radio"][checked]');
console.log(checkedInput.value);
```

Take note that you should make sure that your HTML string is safe to insert into the DOM. Malicious `<script>`, `<style>` and `<object>` elements (to name a few) can wreck havoc on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.querySelector('input:checked')
```